# HTML5 Canvas Drawing App Issue

Tags: html, canvas

I have implement all the function to draw on the canvas like drawFree,Line,Triangle,Star But when I am Selecting other tool,it also draw the previous figure ex:If I have Selected drawFree at first then it is working fine,and when I select draw Line tool to draw a Straight Line,it calls the previous function too.

**javascript**

```
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',draw_Line);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',stop_Draw_Line);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',draw_Dragging_Line);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',draw_Free);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',stop_Draw);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',draw_Dragging);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',draw_Eraser);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',draw_Eraser_Dragging);
                                    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',stop_Eraser);
                switch(str)
                {
                    case "DrawFree":
                                    toolselect=1;
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',draw_Free);
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',stop_Draw);
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',draw_Dragging);
                                    break;
                    case "Line":    toolselect=2;
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',draw_Line);
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',stop_Draw_Line);
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',draw_Dragging_Line);
                                    break;

                    case "Circle":  toolselect=3;
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',draw_Line);
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',stop_Draw_Line);
                                    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',draw_Dragging_Line);
                                    break;
```

**css**

```
    <aside class="leftcontainer">
        <div class="leftHeader">Tools</div>
        <div class="leftDimPanel"></div>
        <div class="toolset">
        <div class="tool" id="DrawFree" onClick="setActiveb('DrawFree')">Draw Free</div>
        <div class="tool" id="Line" onClick="setActiveb('Line')">Line</div>
        <div class="tool" id="Circle" onClick="setActiveb('Circle')">Circle</div>
        <div class="tool" id="Rectangle" onClick="setActiveb('Rectangle')">Rectangle</div>
        <div class="tool" id="Polygon" onClick="setActiveb('Polygon')">Polygon</div>
        <div class="tool" id="Star" onClick="setActiveb('Star')">Star</div>
        <div class="tool" id="Eraser" onClick="setActiveb('Eraser')">Eraser</div>
        </div>
        </aside>
```

how can I remove all event at once from canvas?
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning of your script you need to save canvas context to variable:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Then you need to reset current path by `context.beginPath();` before drawing new figure.

Check this on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beginpath.asp).

Comment: i have done all the things and i have resolved the problem but what i want to do optimise the code

Comment: If you provide complete code (e.g. in snippet), we could try to optimize it.

Comment: the only thing i mess up with is removeListener lines

Comment: Sorry, could not give you an advise with that. If I answered your original question, please mark it as answer. Thanx!